# Multi part form data using PHP. (Image Upload)

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm having a problem with my php file and being able to upload images to a folder. I'm rather new to php so I'm a bit rusty with the jargon. This code allows an admin user to add new products to a store by adding text fields and uploading images. The text is fine, the problem lies with the images not uploading to the specified folder. The database table recognises an update has taken place, but with the php code listed below, this is how it updates...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbrRt.png

Any Help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
<?php

include('../connect.php');

$inserted = insert($_FILES['addimage1'], 'image1');
$inserted = insert($_FILES['addimage2'], 'image2');
$inserted = insert($_FILES['addimage3'], 'image3');

function insert($file, $image_col_name)
{
    $addid= $_POST['addrow'];

    $addproduct= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['addproduct']));
    $addprice= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['addprice']));
    $addprevprice= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['addprevprice']));
    $adddetails= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['adddetails']));

    $addimage = mysql_real_escape_string($file['name']);
    $addimagetemp = mysql_real_escape_string($file['tmp_name']);
    $addimagetype = mysql_real_escape_string($file['type']);
    $addimagesize = mysql_real_escape_string($file['size']); 

    if (!empty($addimage))
    {

        if ($addimagetype == 'image/gif' || $addimagetype == 'image/jpg' || $addimagetype == 'image/jpeg' && $addimagesize > 0 && $addimagesize < 2000000)
        {
            move_uploaded_file($addimagetemp,"../img/camera/$addimage");

            $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details, $image_col_name)"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails', '$addimage')";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p>file needs to be a jpg/gif or file size too big.</p>";
            die();  
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        $query = "INSERT INTO admincamera (product, price, prevprice, details)"."VALUES('$addproduct', '$addprice', '$addprevprice', '$adddetails')";
    }

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    return true;
}
?>
```

Comment: have you checked directory permission

Comment: checked directory permission. what operating system you are using?

Comment: did you try to print $addimage to see it is getting image name?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the directory permission OR else please provide the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Give permission to upload in directory, try to run chmod in folder directory

```
chmod -R 777 image_folder
```